# Dynamically set properties in pipeline component

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a custom pipeline component which Encrypts, ZIPs and password protects a message prior to emailing.  I have a requirement to dynamically set the password from the orchestration.  I can't find any examples on how to do this although I see that there is BTS.SendPipelineConfig.  I presume I pass the altered config to this, but I don't know how to access the existing xml config for the pipeline.

Are there any tutorials or examples avaiable for this? I have searched to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better served to add a context property to the message that is set in the orchestration.  This context property could be read by your pipeline component.

Comment: Thanks Ben, the requirement has disappeared for the moment but I will revisit.

Answer (score 0):

After some deliberation I have decided to write the code within my custom component.  I would have preferred to keep this component generic but writing the password within it makes it more secure and quicker to develop.